# 9-patch for emulating card with full bleed look in the GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm emulating the `Card` object due to its limitations in `CardScrollView`, and need a full bleed image with the text at the bottom.  It looks like the standard `Card` has some 9-patch drawable or something doing the opacity shading in the background.  Has anyone found it or made one for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue and ended up drawing transparent `.png` which fades at the bottom.

Some time later, I've looked into `GlassHome.apk`, which you can find on the github.

I found there these 3 images in `drawable-hdpi` folder.

Hope, they'll be useful to you:

1. `overlay_large.png`
   [image: overlay_large.png]
2. `overlay_medium.png`
   [image: overlay_medium.png]
3. `overlay_small.png`
   [image: overlay_small.png]